# Error when updating models Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller, laravel-5

I have a model Article:

```
class Article extends Model
{

    protected $fillable = [
        'title',
        'slug',
        'body',
        'category_id'
    ];

    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');
    }

}
```

When I go to edit form and click update, I get this error:

```
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '_method' in 'field list' (SQL: update `articles` set `_method` = PATCH, `_token` = s9ee0UZQwqFbnjuzGv9pSMdz2xpudks715WOhbL1, `title` = 111, `slug` = 111, `category_id` = 1, `body` = 111, `updated_at` = 2015-06-01 22:51:10)
```

What could cause the problem?

That's the `update()` method:

```
public function update(Article $article, ArticleRequest $request)
{
    $article->update($request->all());

    return redirect('admin/article');
}
```

Comment: Looks like the request object doesn't contain a user id. Perhaps get it through `Auth::user()->id` or similar?

Comment: @JoelHinz, How do I add to the request user_id? `\Auth::user()->id;` I get `1`.

Comment: Can you try this ? $request->merge(['user_id' => Auth::user()->id]); before doing $article->fill(...)

Comment: @ChainList, error: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'first-article' for key 'articles_slug_unique' (SQL: insert into `articles` (`title`, `slug`, `category_id`, `body`, `user_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (First article, first-article, 1, lorem ipsum, 1, 2015-06-01 17:45:57, 2015-06-01 17:45:57))

Comment: Try to carefully read your error. SQL is telling you that you try to insert an article with a slug 'first-article' that already exists in your database. :)

Comment: @ChainList, All right, I'm trying to update the article, instead of adding a new!

Comment: Do an $article->update($request->all()); instead of ->save(). You are trying to INSERT INTO instead of UPDATE one.

Comment: @ChainList, error: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '_method' in 'field list' (SQL: update `articles` set `_method` = PATCH, `_token` = CZfHGyuys2Cvz1LC1pXCTkghV1tJDO67kRDcLfg0, `title` = First article, `slug` = first-article, `category_id` = 2, `body` = lorem ipsum 11, `user_id` = 1, `updated_at` = 2015-06-01 18:01:33)

Comment: You have to remove '_token' and '_method' from you inputs. $request->except('_token', '_token', '_method');

Comment: @ChainList, It did not help, the error remains!

Comment: @Pearson, update your question with your actual file please.